# when stub Time in rspec integration tests, any way to print actual time?

Tags: rspec, stub

When running some long integration test sequences, we stub Time to have controllable relative timing of certain events,

However, in the some test suite logs, we'd like to print actual elapsed time for certain parts of the test. (As one example, we repeat certain sequences a lot of times, and want to measure any degradation in test performance as the test dataset grows larger.)

Is there any way to access the true system time during tests once Time is stubbed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try calling `unstub` as described [here](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/2-11/docs/method-stubs/stub-on-any-instance-of-a-class#any-instance-unstub).

If you only need to set a specific epoch, you might try [timecop](http://github.com/travisjeffery/timecop) and its 'travel' option'

Comment: I would recommend also Timecop gem